# How to add base64 images as inline attachment to a mail in ActiveMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am trying to send a base64 image as an inline attachment in Ruby on rails using Active Mailer but it just do not work.

I found this way to add the attachment:

```
def inline_base64(name, content)
    attachments.inline[name] =
    {
      mime_type: 'image/png',
      content: content,
      encoding: "base64"
    }
  end
```

I call the method like this

```
inline_base64('first_client.png', client[:image64])
```

where the first param is only the name and the other is a base64 image as a string

In the erb file I try to insert the image like:

```
<%= image_tag attachments['first_client.png'].url, size:'90' %>
```

But when I receive the mail it only shows the image as broken:

[image: image broken]

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base64 is an encoded representation of the data in a file.

> Note the difference between Base64 and DataURL.
>
> DataURL strings start with `data:image/png;base64,` or a similar string. If this is your case, then your **base 64 encoded data** is everything after the `,`: `base_64 = content.split(',')[1]`

This base 64 data is just the result of reading a file and encoding its data as base 64:

```
content = Base64.encode64(File.read('your/path.png'))
```

You only need to *undo* the encoding to get the exact result as what the function `File.read` would return:

```
data = Base64.decode64(content)
```

Your method will end as the following:

```
def inline_base64(name, content)
  attachments.inline[name] = Base64.decode64(content)
end
```

If you are still getting a broken image check if your `content` starts with a DataURL string and strip that out.